# Localhost permissions given different values in fireftp and cs4 dreamweaver

Tags: permissions, ftp, localhost

While testing a file uploader on my localhost ( mamp on mac ) I've hit a problem.
Trying to fix a folder permissions problem, I used CS4 Dreamweaver's permissions screen to set 0777 permissions. However these wouldn't apply and stayed stuck on 0, so I opened fireftp and accessed the folder in the local panel. The permissions there are 0777.

So I have a folder that has permissions of 0 and 0777 at the same time. How can I resolve this and make sure the permissions are 0777?

Answer (score 1):

> Actually, now that I think of it, you
>   can do the exact same thing using the
>   finder with a right click on your
>   folder, and read the info...

I've done this and set all usergroups to read/write, but the problem persists. Is there a test I can do to see what permissions are actually being given?

So, either:-

1) I do have a pemissions problem and my mac is playing up

or

2) there's a problem with my script

Comment: did you try the terminal tip I gave you? That will definitely give you the last word of it.
did you apply your changes to all files and subfolders in the finder?

Comment: I'll try this evening and comment back

Answer (score 0):

Well, it can't be both at the same time.

If it's local and you want to know which one it is, just open a terminal, and type `ls -l Site/your_folder/your_sub_folder` and press enter. It will show you a list of your files, their owner and permissions.

You can navigate through your folders by using `cd folder`and `cd ..` to move back up, and use your tab key to auto-complete a folder's name.

Actually, now that I think of it, you can do the exact same thing using the finder with a right click on your folder, and read the info...